# Django Q lookup works but displays << MISSING VARIABLE "request.GET.q" >> in my lookup field

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I use Q lookups in all my projects but this is the first I have run into this.  First off, the lookup works as expected, but the lookup field still displays `<< MISSING VARIABLE "request.GET.q" >>` when refreshing the page. If the lookup didn't work, I could probably find the issue but I'm a bit stumped in this one.  Below is by view and the template form.  Thank you.

**View**

```
def product_list(request):
    queryset_list = Product.objects.prefetch_related('images').select_subclasses()
    query = request.GET.get("q")
    if query:
        queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(
            Q(name__icontains=query)
        ).distinct()

    paginator = Paginator(queryset_list, 10)
    page_request_var = "page"
    page = request.GET.get(page_request_var)
    try:
        queryset = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        queryset = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        queryset = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    form = forms.ProductClassForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        return redirect('dashboard:product-add')

    ctx = {
        'form': form,
        "object_list": queryset,
        "title": "Products",
        "page_request_var": page_request_var,
    }
    return TemplateResponse(request, 'dashboard/product/list.html', ctx)
```

**Lookup Form**

```
<form method='GET' action=''>
  <label for="full-text">Search Product List</label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Keywords and Press Enter" class="search-input" name="q" value='{{ request.GET.q }}'>
</form>
```

[image]

Comment: What is the URL using which you have accessed the page in the screenshot? Does it contain a query params `q`?

Comment: Maybe you should move POST detection code at the top of function (it is also a hacky way of POST detection, it should be done via `if request.method == 'POST':` ). If that does not work, try to simplify things, for example to remove custom manager `.select_subclasses()`, also change `if query:` to `if query is not None:`

Comment: `if query is not None` seemed to work.  Thank you for your help.